# Running RootsMagic in WINE on Linux

Tags: ancestry.com, family-tree, family-tree-maker

I've been running linux for over 20 years, and haven't ever bothered to learn how to run Win programs in WINE, but now I want to use RootsMagic to completely back up my enormous Ancestry.com tree. I purchased FTM and installed it on my husband's Win box, but it refuses to download the whole tree plus media. It always stalls out. I gave it the gedcom, but there are no media that way.

PlayOnLinux on my "Kpop" (KDE Plasma on PopOS) install seems unable to find the .exe file I downloaded, and all the help docs seem to start *after* the application is installed.

Any hints?

Comment: Warning: Using TreeShare or FTM's sync will not do a complete backup of an online Ancestry tree.  Comments and Weblinks are not synced, and the only media that are pulled down (when the sync works) are the pages which are attached to the tree. For multi-page documents, you are likely to get only the first page of the document. Any non-indexed pages that you've linked via Weblinks will have to be downloaded manually.  Magic Guide from RootsMagic is at  https://files.rootsmagic.com/guides/Magic_Guide_TreeShare_Ancestry_FAQ.pdf 
You'll get a head start but not the entire tree.

Comment: Please let us know if you are running RM8 or RM9 or some earlier version. If you need to specify a version of Windows for WINE please let us know what you've tried.

Comment: I never was able to get RM8 to work entirely properly with wine.  RM7 works perfectly however.  If you need RM8, your best bet is to install it under Windows under Virtualbox.

Comment: Have you considered using Gramps which runs natively in linux? - Posting as a comment as it's not an answer to the question, but might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

From Wine HQ's [Wine User's Guide](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide)

The opening intro to section 3, Using Wine, has this note under the code examples:

> The first argument should be the name of the file you want wine to execute. If the executable is in the Path environment variable, you can simply give the executable file name. However, if the executable is not in Path, you must give the full path to the executable. See [#How to run Windows programs from the command line](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#How_to_run_Windows_programs_from_the_command_line) for more information.

Put the full path to the *.exe file and see if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't, please update your question to let us know. Seeing the error message you get may be helpful.

Comment: I'm parking this link here because it doesn't directly address the problem in the Q, but may prove helpful later. https://community.rootsmagic.com/t/running-rm-9-on-linux-wine/6363/24